# Use a function return value directly as reference in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Recently I have to use C++ for a course at university. I'm aware of the concept of pointers and references, but i'm humbling at a specific point.

consider following class definition:

```
class test{
    public:
        test(int i);
        ~test();
        int* getint();
    private:
        int *asdf;
};

test::test(int i){
     asdf = new int();
    *asdf = i;
}

int* test::getint(){
    return asdf;
}
```

and the following code:

```
void fun1(int*& i){
    *i +=1;
}

int main(){
    test *a = new test(1);
    fun1(a->getint());
}
```

If i'm compiling it with g++ i'll get an error message:

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘int*&’ from an rvalue of type ‘int*’
```

I see where the problem is, and that it can be solved by declaring a new pointer like this:

```
int main(){
    test *a = new test(1);
    int* b = a->getint();
    fun1(b);
}
```

But is there any other way to use the return value directly as a reference?
If my C++ code is terrible, you're welcome to correct it (it's basicly my first week of C++).

EDIT: changed fun1 to use reference and corrected initilization of class variable (as suggested by enrico.bacis

Comment: `int* asdf = new int();` - You're creating a local variable that shadows your data member. You can get warnings for that with the right options.

Comment: Where exactly are the references?  All I'm seeing are pointers.

Comment: Apart from the logic error, it compiles fine in GCC 4.7.2: http://liveworkspace.org/code/e11908eab4281b5c1e73b980a0743ca6

Comment: If you fix the error mentioned above, it works (though with pointers, not with references)  http://ideone.com/a735u5

Comment: To summerize what chris said: replace `int* asdf = new int();` with `asdf = new int();`

Comment: IIRC, you can't use references that way -- a temporary bound to a reference is always `const`.  This should work if you change the signature of `fun1` to `void fun1(int * const & i)`.  (In this case, `i` is a reference to a constant pointer to an int.)

Comment: ok i edited the fun1 to accept a reference. sorry i've missed the the first time, since it was the problem i've asked about.

Answer (score 3):

You are defining a new `asdf` variable in the constructor of the class test that shadows the instance variable.

Change the line:

```
int* asdf = new int();
```

with:

```
asdf = new int();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues, as in C++ you have to manage memory properly and cannot just call new all the time without taking care of deletion later.

I think this

```
void fun1(int* i)
{
  *i +=1;
}
```

will give the +=1 a higher operator precedence than the * so you need to do:

```
void fun1(int* i)
{
  (*i) +=1;
}
```

Note that the function needs to take `int*` as a parameter not `int *&`. You would only take `int *&` if you want to modify the pointer itself, rather than what it points to. And in such a case you could not pass in the return value of `getint()` which appears to be giving you your compiler error.

Comment: thanks for that info. in the original file there is a destructor, which deletes the pointer.